How to Display Data from Multiple Devices Together in a ThingsBoard Timeseries Table Widget?
Question:
I am working with ThingsBoard, an open-source IoT platform, and I have multiple devices sending timeseries data to the platform. I am using the timeseries table widget to visualize this data.
Current Setup:
I have the timeseries table widget set up to display data from my devices. Currently, the widget displays the data in the form of tabs, with each tab representing data from a single device.
Objective:
I want the timeseries table widget to display data from all my devices together in a single table, without using tabs. This way, I can see and compare the data from all devices in one unified view.
Is it possible to configure the timeseries table widget in ThingsBoard to display data from multiple devices together in a single table without using tabs?
Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Ask in a ThingsBoard forum ...

you have to create custom widget for that
